# Define recursive algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

I have tried to understand how I need to define the complexity of algorithms. For an example I have this 2 algorithms:

```
static int z1 = 23;
static int z2 = 27;
static int z3 = 26;

void g(int n, int i) {
        if (!i) return;
        for (int j=2*n; j > 0; --j) {
            g(n,i-1);
        }
    } 

void f(int n) {
    if (!n) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < z1%10; ++i) {
        f(n/(z3%10+2));
    }
    g(n,z2%3);
    f(n/(z3%10+2));
    g(n,z2%3);
}
```

Let's look for a function g:

```
void g(int n, int i) {                 T1
        if (!i) return;                T2
        for (int j=2*n; j > 0; --j) {  T3
            g(n,i-1);                  T(i-1)
        }
    }
```

> T(n) = T1 + T2 + (2n) * (T3 + T(i-1)) + T2.

If I asumme that

> T1 = T2 = T3 = 1.

Then i have:

> T(n) = 1 + 1 + 1 + (2n) * (1 + T(i-1)) + 1 = 3 + 2n + 2n * T(i-1).

Now I take away constants and have:

> T(n) = n + n * T(i-1) = n(1+T(i-1)) that equal to O(n^2).

Now we can look for second function f:

```
void f(int n) {                         
    if (!n) return;                     T1
    for (int i = 0; i < z1%10; ++i) {   T2
        f(n/(z3%10+2));                 T3
    }                 
    g(n,z2%3);                          T4
    f(n/(z3%10+2));                     T5
    g(n,z2%3);                          T6
}
```

> Where T3 = T5 = T(n/8).
>   Where T1 = T2 = 1.
>   Where T4 = T6 = O(n^2) = n^2.
>
> T(n) = T1 + 3(T2 + T(n/8)) + T4 + T(n/8) + T6.
>
> T(n) = 1 + 3(1 + T(n/8)) + n^2 + T(n/8) + n^2.
>
> T(n) = 4 + 4T(n/8) + 2n^2 | :2.
>
> T(n) = 2 + 2T(n/8) + n^2.

From this, I get O(n^3log n).

Am I right understand this? Or I have a big problems? Because I don't know how I can check myself.

Answer (score 2):

In recursive caculation `g` function only `i` is changed, so its complexity is `T(n, i)`. For it we have

`T(n, i) = 2n * T(n, i - 1)`

so

`T(n, i) = O((2n)^i)`

Your `f` function implements some algorithm of type "divide and conquer". Original problem divided on several smaller tasks. For calculating complexity of such algorithms the master theorem is applied. You can read about that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem. I think reading this give you more than my explanation. According to this theorem 
complexity `G(n)` of function `f` is

```
    G(n) = 4G(n / 8) + 2T(n, 0)
    G(n) = 4G(n / 8) + 2
    G(n) = O(n^(2 / 3))
```

Comment: This should be a comment. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your first function's cost could be written as:

> G(n) = 1 + 2n * G(n - 1)

which results in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

As for the other function, I assume that you wanted to say:

```
static int z3 = 26; // and not 'z2'
```

Moreover, since the values are hardcoded, why you keep the code dense, rewrite to this:

```
void f(int n) {
    if (!n) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        f(n/8);
    }
    g(n, 0);
    f(n/8);
    g(n, 0);
}
```

and now the complexity can be determined much more easily, like:

> F(n) = 1 + 3F(n/8) + G(0) + F(n/8) + G(0) = 1 + 4F(n/8) + 2G(0)

and we know that `G(0) = 1`, thus the above becomes:

> F(n) = 3 + 4F(n/8)

where one can apply the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) and according to this online [Project Nayuki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript), we get:

> Θ(n^ ( log_8{4} ) )